# Get Label aligned when in flexlayout and frame xamarin forms

Tags: xamarin.forms

I have a flexlayout when a display some items in a frame, but all the items that have labels with text on 2 lines the icon gets pushed up and the label text do not align with each other. Any suggestions of what I am doing wrong?

[image]

my code

```
<Grid>
    <ScrollView>
        <FlexLayout
            Padding="8"
            AlignContent="Start"
            AlignItems="Start"
            BindableLayout.ItemsSource="{Binding MyItems}"
            Direction="Row"
            JustifyContent="Start"
            Wrap="Wrap">
            <BindableLayout.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <StackLayout HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand"
                        Margin="4,4,4,4"
                        FlexLayout.AlignSelf="Start"
                        FlexLayout.Basis="{OnIdiom Phone='50%',
                                                   Tablet='33%'}">
                        <Frame
                            Margin="0"
                            Padding="0"
                            BorderColor="DarkGray"
                            CornerRadius="10"
                            HeightRequest="130"
                            HasShadow="True">

                            <StackLayout VerticalOptions="Center" HorizontalOptions="Center">
                                <Image  Aspect="AspectFit" Source="PhotoIcon.png"
                                        Margin="0,20,0,0" WidthRequest="50" HeightRequest="50"/>

                                <Label  Text="{Binding Name}" Margin="0,10,0,10" />
                            </StackLayout>

                        </Frame>
                    </StackLayout>
                </DataTemplate>
            </BindableLayout.ItemTemplate>
        </FlexLayout>
    </ScrollView>
</Grid>
```

Comment: When you say label text is not aligning how exactly do you expect it to align itself?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Improve your code

```
<Label  Text="{Binding Name}"  HorizontalTextAlignment="Center" VerticalTextAlignment="Center" Margin="0,10,0,10" />
```

## Update:

Because `StackLayout` will not fit the size of its child elements ,so I suggest you can use `Grid` instead of it.

```
<Grid VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand">
      <Grid.RowDefinitions>
          <RowDefinition Height="0.5*" />
          <RowDefinition Height="0.5*" />                                       
      </Grid.RowDefinitions>

      <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                        
      </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>


      <Image  Grid.Row="0" Aspect="AspectFit" Source="PhotoIcon.png" Margin="0,20,0,0" WidthRequest="50" HeightRequest="50"/>

      <Label  Grid.Row="1" Text="{Binding Name}" Margin="0,10,0,10" HorizontalTextAlignment="Center" VerticalTextAlignment="Center"/>
</Grid>
```

Comment: Zhang sorry original code had  HorizontalTextAlignment="Center" VerticalTextAlignment="Center" already, because I cleaned it up for posting I must have missed it . still not working

Comment: It works fine on my project . You can share a sample which contains the issue so that I can test it on my side .

Comment: I have to build a small project and post it.

Comment: I have created a dummy project showing the issue  https://github.com/developer9969/SimpleAlignAppIssue. (android project has 2 pics)

Comment: OK, I will check it.

Comment: It works fine on my device .You can try to debug it on another device.

Comment: Maybe it has crash. Delete the folder bin and obj both in your PCL and android project .Then clean and rebuild it.

Comment: it still pushes the icon up I would be interested if you would show a pic of what you have.thanks anyway for your help